# How to filter queries with date range in django

Tags: python, django

Here how can i filter all products which are added from within the past one month to this date.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    added = model.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def all_products(request):
    all_products = Product.objects.all()
    recently_added_products = Product.objects.filter(...)
    context = {'all_products':all_products,'recent_products':recent_products}
    return render(request,'products_list.html',context)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `range` filter to specify a date range (inclusive):

```
from django.utils import timezone

today = timezone.now().date()

Product.objects.filter(added__range=[today - timezone.timedelta(days=30), today])
```

Answer (score 1):

We first need to calculate the previous month. We can for example use [**`relativedelta`** [python-doc]](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) from the [**`python-dateutil`** package [PyPi]](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/). We can thus install this package with:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Then we can filter the `Product`s such that we get all `Product`s that were added after or one `prev_month` with `prev_month` the `datetime` object that is exactly one month ago:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now

def all_products(request):
    all_products = Product.objects.all()
    prev_month = now() - relativedelta(months=1)
    recently_added_products = Product.objects.filter(added__gte=prev_month)
    context = {'all_products':all_products,'recent_products':recent_products}
    return render(request,'products_list.html',context)
```

We thus use the [**`__gte`** lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte) to filter all `Product`s with an `added` date greater than one month ago.

> **Note**: if you often filter, it might be better to add a [**`db_index=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index) on your `added` field:
>
> ```
> class Product(models.Model):
>     # ...
>     added = model.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
> ```

Comment: i got this `from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil'`

Comment: @Alicesmith: you need to install the package, with `pip install python-dateutil` for example

Comment: i implemented unknown_user solution but your solution also worked.Thank you .Is there any difference between these two solution.Which solution should i prefer more?

Comment: @Alicesmith: there are two small differences: `unknown_user` goes back 30 days in time, whereas this one a month (so for a month with 31/28/29 days) that is different. Furthermore if a `Product` is added in the future, `unknown_user`'s solution will exclude that, whereas this one only looks for everythin added *after* this timestamp (so including "future" `Product`s). Although since you use `auto_add_now`, that should (not) happen.

Comment: Okay i got this.Thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can use python [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and do something like this

```
import datetime

recently_added_products = Product.objects.filter(date__gte=datetime.date(2019, 7, 1), date__lte=datetime.date(2019, 7, 31))
```